# Sphinx autodoc not using current docstring of method

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

When I run `make html` with sphinx autodoc enabled, the functions' docstrings are not the actual docstrings.

I have the path configured in my conf.py file

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../")) # Where the module is located
```

The output of autodoc:

[image]

The actual docstring:

[image]

Content of my .rst file:

```
Subreddit
=========================================

.. autoclass:: redditeasy.Subreddit
   :members:
```

The output of autodoc is the outdated one. I changed the docstring multiple times but autodoc just kept using the old version.

I cleared cache and uninstalled autodoc multiple times but none of them did anything. Why does this happen? How can I update the docstrings?

Comment: When you "cleared cache", did you do `make clean` to do so? Sphinx only detects changes in document source files, not package source files.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I did @StevePiercy

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @StevePiercy https://github.com/MakufonSkifto/RedditEasy/tree/main/docs is exactly what I use.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I used `main` branch to build the docs. See before and after I edited the docstring: https://imgur.com/a/5L1UEFh It sounds like you are not editing `redditeasy/subreddit.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It was giving a "no module found" error.